# How to loop data with that will have different styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I loop data that will have different styles such as colors and icons in a better way than the code below? The code below works but I want to have more categories to loop through and the code is getting long. Is there a better way to do this without changing the backend?

I'm using Next.js and Firebase for backend, map looping "Food" `collection` with product `documents` and categories in `fields`. Only one `id` in the food group can be true for each item.

```
          {food.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              {/* Fruits category*/}
              {Object.keys(item.fruitsCategory).length > 0 && (
                <div>
                  {/* Apples */}
                  {item.fruitsCategory.category.id === 1 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <AppleIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#1BAB33]">Apples</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {/* Bananas */}
                  {item.fruitsCategory.category.id === 2 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <BananaIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#C6B027]">Bananas</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {/* Oranges */}
                  {item.fruitsCategory.category.id === 3 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <OrangeIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#FAB71A]">Oranges</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {/* Strawberries */}
                  {item.fruitsCategory.category.id === 4 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <StrawberryIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#D13131]">Strawberries</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

              {/* Meat category */}
              {Object.keys(item.meatCategory).length > 0 && (
                <div>
                  {/* Cow meat */}
                  {item.meatCategory.category.id === 1 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <CowIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#006989]">Cow meat</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {/* Chicken meat */}
                  {item.meatCategory.category.id === 2 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <ChickenIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#01A7C2]">Chicken meat</p>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {/* Pig meat */}
                  {item.meatCategory.category.id === 3 && (
                    <div className="flex gap-2">
                      <PigIcon />
                      <p className="text-[#18AFC8]">Pig meat</p>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
                </div>
              )}
```

Comment: What does `food` look like? Most likely, it's in some sort of antipattern shape that causes you to deal with it in a nasty way (`Object.keys()` is a red flag).

Comment: If you cannot change the food array. As @ggorlen stated, it looks nasty as hek. You could make a constant object such as "fruits" that has the ID of each as a key and then text,icon,class as properties. Then in the loop just use `fruits[item.fruitsCategory.category.id].icon` ,`fruits[item.fruitsCategory.category.id].class`,  `fruits[item.fruitsCategory.category.id].text` to render it